# NullpointerException while accessing Spring Bean factory + tomcat 8 startup

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat8

We recently migrated from java 7 to java 8 and tomcat 6 to tomcat 8. All was well before migration and now we are getting below issue during deployment of our services and deployment fails and tomcat does not start.

What is crazy is that, this does not happen always and is intermittent (occurs once in three or four deployments).

Below is the stack trace that we see during deployment.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.async.ClassB.createClassC(ClassB.java)
    at com.async.ClassA.afterPropertiesSet(ClassA.java)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
```

Existing code:
In our code we have a singleton classA, injected with singleton ClassB. And also a prototype ClassC used in ClassB.

In ClassA, we have afterPropertiesSet(), where-in we are getting instance of ClassB using applicationContext.

In ClassB we are trying to get the instance of ClassC using BeanFactory.

Exact code looks like this.

```
public ClassA implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {

     private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

     public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        ClassB classB = 
            (ClassB)applicationContext.getBean("classB");       
        registry.registerAsyncListener(this);
     }

     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
     }
}

public ClassB  implements Lifecycle, DisposableBean, BeanFactoryAware {

    private AsyncMessageListener createClassC(ClassA classA) {
        logger.warn("bean factory value ... " + getBeanFactory());      
        ClassC classC = (ClassC) getBeanFactory().getBean("classC", ClassC.class);        
        return classC;
    }

    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    public start(){ // some code
    }

    public stop(){ // some code
    }

    public isRunning(){ // some code
    }

    public destroy(){ // some code
    }

}
```

When we added more loggers, what we saw is that beanFactory ggets the null value intermittently and hence the NullpointerException.

I am not very much into springs, and did some basic research. It looks like like there is no code issue and still i wonder why BeanFactory is getting null value.

We tried replacing BeanFactory with ApllicationContext the still the same issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: whichline gies you the error?

Comment: Below line gives the error.  
 ClassC classC = (ClassC) getBeanFactory().getBean("classC", ClassC.class);

Logger added indicates that,
bean factory value ... null.